# "Spotlight" like component for Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, components

I am just thinking about ways to improve the user experience for our data entry application and thought about a Mac OS X Spotlight like search bar which allow the user to search for arbitrary terms and pick from a list of choices that match the terms.

I imagine something that is capable of showing categories (like contacts, appointments, mails etc.) and the related results simultaneously.

Do you know of any Swing component that is readily available somewhere, so I would not need to create the UI part again, but concentrate on the actual "search plugins"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, I cannot think of a "ready made" component for what you are looking at but you may find the following interesting:

[macwidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/)

This is a collection of "mac style" widgets, such as a "heads up display" and sidebar lists similar to the ones you find in iTunes.

You may want to try adapting some of them to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Like the search tool?  or the "spotlight" visual where everything is dimmed but there's a light shining on the things that match?

If you're talking about a UI component, the "Swing Hacks" O'Reilly book has a spotlight example.

If you're talking about search/indexing, i'd recomment Apache Lucene.  Not sure that anyone

[edit:my answer was cut off right here?]

has a ready made fully functional search results browser like spotlight has now.

Comment: thanks for the -1 without a comment.  although it looks like my answer got cut off in the middle somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Lucene. I will have a look at their browser.

Comment: If you go with lucene, also look at Luke, which is a lucene index browser thing which works awesome for debugging issues/contents of your indexes